# how to get values in form-data from postman addon nodejs express

Tags: node.js, node-rest-client

I am using node js with express framework, restful api.
I want to post values using 'form-data' option in postman addon.

I am able to post values using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option and am able to get values like `req.body.username`, `req.body.email`, etc. This is working fine, but I need 'form-data' option also.

If I use "form-data" option then I am not able to get the post values please help me how to get values using this option 'form-data' in postman addon.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried postman. 
It sends the header as content type multipart/form-data.

You need another package to handle that.

They are linked in body-parser repo at the top. 
For example: [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy#readme), [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty#readme)

Comment: I have used this in my already
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
but i am still didn't get any response please help me
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body);
 res.send( response);
});

Answer (score 0):

Use req.fields and use 'express-formidable' to get form-data from postman.